# SQL Retrieving values from a statement with multiple selects

Tags: sql, vb.net, select

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT count (1) FROM users AS total_drafts WHERE version_replace = @sid 
SELECT count (1) AS unpublished_drafts FROM users WHERE version_replace = @sid AND moderated = 0 
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = @sid ORDER By ID DESC
```

Which appears to be correct. However I'm having difficulty extracting the fields from the results. In vb.net I am using this code fragment:

```
 While r.Read()
                    Dim o_email As String = CStr(r("email"))
                    Dim o_first_name As String = CStr(r("first_name"))
                    Dim o_last_name As String = CStr(r("last_name"))
```

Which is causing this error: **System.IndexOutOfRangeException: email**
I have checked the sql is being exucuted correctly. The sql I've posted is simply replacing a simpler statement which was feeding into the code fragment perfectly.

Why is this and how do I correct it?

the correct way:

```
While r.Read()
                    total_drafts = CInt(r("total_drafts"))
                End While

                r.NextResult()
                While r.Read()
                    unpublished_drafts = CInt(r("unpublished_drafts"))
                End While

                error_status.Text = total_drafts & " " & unpublished_drafts

                r.NextResult()
                While r.Read()
                    Dim o_email As String = CStr(r("email"))
                    Dim o_first_name As String = CStr(r("first_name"))
                    Dim o_last_name As String = CStr(r("last_name"))
```

Comment: why don't you give a try with indexes of the column rather than the column name, That might help you out.

Comment: Can you post an example output (from the SQL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: `r.NextResult()` instead of `r.ReadNext()`, `r.ReadNext()` is for a DataTableReader

Assuming you are calling the whole sql statement in one go, the problem is that `r.Read()` will use the first datatable that is returned for the first statement(`SELECT count (1) FROM users AS total_drafts WHERE version_replace = @sid` ), which does not contain the email etc. fields.

You have to call `r.NextResult()` twice, this will move the datareader to the 3rd dataset that will contain the data from `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = @sid ORDER By ID DESC`

Comment: Do I call r.ReadNext in the first r.Read while loop or out of it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand you're trying to execute multiple statements, right?
You should separate your SQL statements with a semicolon and change the reader when you've finished with the previous [one](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4638/how-to-run-through-multiple-datareader-results/).

UPDATE:

I usually use stored procedures and return parameters for counters.
Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetUsers (@sid INT, @unpublished INT OUTPUT)

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @total_drafts INT
DECLARE @unpublished_drafts INT;

SELECT @total_drafts = count (1) FROM users WHERE version_replace = @sid 
SELECT @unpublished_drafts = count (1) FROM users WHERE version_replace = @sid AND moderated = 0 

SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = @sid ORDER By ID DESC

    RETURN(@total_drafts)

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning three datasets. If "r" is a DataReader (unclear from your question) then you need to call;

r.NextResult

between your lines of code, like this;

```
While r.Read()                    
    Dim o_email As String = CStr(r("email"))      
    r.NextResult()              
    Dim o_first_name As String = CStr(r("first_name"))  
    r.NextResult()                  
    Dim o_last_name As String = CStr(r("last_name"))
```

One other possible explanation (again, unclear) is that you messed up your first column name ("email"), this would also give an out of range exception.